# Analytics UTM tags displaying scrambled campaign and medium info

Tags: google-analytics, analytics

We put links in our PDF invoices so people can click to get services, more info, manuals etc. Google Analytics reporting shows some scrambled text for some reason: [image]

I went through the PDFs and the links all seem to work and return the expected result but analytics displays scrambled campaign and medium info.

Here is how I set up the campaigns

> url.com/category.php?utm_medium=invoice&utm_source=pdf&utm_campaign=air+shower+ad
>
> url.com/category.php?utm_medium=invoice&utm_source=pdf&utm_campaign=alarm+led+combo+ad
>
> url.com/category.php?utm_medium=invoice&utm_source=pdf&utm_campaign=binder+ad
>
> url.com/category.php?utm_medium=invoice&utm_source=pdf&utm_campaign=biosafe+cleanroom+ad
>
> url.com/category.php?utm_medium=invoice&utm_source=pdf&utm_campaign=biosafe+sink+ad

Comment: Give us a link to this pdf, it is very strange.

Comment: hello i am expereincing the same issue on some of my links, did you find out why?